# Problem with retaining aspect rato

Tags: ffmpeg

(Before you ask, resolution and aspect ratio need to be like this for a reason)

I tried using this to make sure the aspect ratio stayed the same, because for some reason it doesn't

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video -aspect 16:10 -an -b 6000K -minrate 6000K -maxrate 6000K output.m2v`

Now that command works for 4:3 but not 16:10, it just ignores it basically. So I tried using this, SAR is what the base file is and the DAR should be the -aspect command right?

`ffmpeg -i P3CT001_01.mp4 -vf scale=640:368,setsar=sar=10/11 -aspect 400/253 -c:v mpeg2video -an -b 6000K -minrate 6000K -maxrate 6000K output.m2v`

Well same issue here, it seems it doesn't like when the last number (So the 10 in 16:10) is more than one digit. Also trying that first command seems to change the resolution when set to 16:10

This issue does not happen with mpeg1